# Navigation - waitForXPath for many xpaths ("Promise.race" like logic )

Tags: node.js, xpath, web-crawler, puppeteer

Im using puppteer to search trough a website . After I click the search button one of two things happen:

- a popup appears .
- navigation to search result page .

I want to wait for either the popup or the result element to appear .

Current solution :

```
 await  page.waitFor(5000)
   const [results, popUpContinueButton ] =
       await Promise.all( [ 
           page.$x("Result page Xpath"),
           page.$x("Pop up Xpath").then((res) => res[0]),
       ])

    if(popUpContinueButton){
        await Promise.all([
            page.evaluate((btn) => btn.click(), popUpContinueButton),
            page.waitForXPath("Result page Xpath")
        ])
    }
...
```

Can I replace  the 5 sec waiting and use the  page.waitForXPath in a  similar way Promise.race (nodeJS ) is used ?

i.e: wait until either the popup or the search results appear

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution . Using the built in Xpath or operator with both xpaths as clauses .

```
 await  page. waitForXPath(`${"Result page Xpath"} | ${"Pop up Xpath"}`)
   const [results, popUpContinueButton ] =
       await Promise.all( [ 
           page.$x("Result page Xpath"),
           page.$x("Pop up Xpath").then((res) => res[0]),
       ])

    if(popUpContinueButton){
        await Promise.all([
            page.evaluate((btn) => btn.click(), popUpContinueButton),
            page.waitForXPath("Result page Xpath")
        ])
    }
...
```